# What to pass as the ColumnSize argument of ODBC SQLBindParameter in a C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, odbc

I am learning how to use the `SQLBindParameter` function. I was going through a couple of examples on the Internet and it is not clear what I should be passing as the 6th argument to the `SQLBindParameter` function.

The example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963(v=vs.85).aspx passes the size of the character array when the C type is `SQL_C_CHAR` and 0 when the C type is `SQL_C_SSHORT`.

```
SQLSMALLINT sCustID;    
SQLCHAR szEmployeeID[EMPLOYEE_ID_LEN];
SQL_DATE_STRUCT dsOrderDate;
SQLINTEGER cbCustID = 0, cbOrderDate = 0, cbEmployeeID = SQL_NTS;
```

...

```
retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, EMPLOYEE_ID_LEN, 0, szEmployeeID, 0, &cbEmployeeID);
retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SSHORT, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &sCustID, 0, &cbCustID);
```

However, an example at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2e/v8r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2e.doc%2Fdbeapc1702.html passes 0 for SQL_C_TCHAR and some positive integers for SQL_C_LONG.

```
long p1 = 10; 
short p2 = 100; 
TCHAR p3[100];
```

...

```
// bind input parameters 
rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, (unsigned short)1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT,
                        SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, 4, 0, &p1, sizeof(p1), &len); 
// check return code ... 

rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, (unsigned short)2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_LONG,
                        SQL_SMALLINT, 2, 0, &p2, sizeof(p2), &len); 
// check return code ... 

len = SQL_NTS; 
rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, (unsigned short)3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TCHAR,
                                SQL_CHAR, 0, 0, &p3[0], 100, &len);
```

Could someone please clarify how exactly do we decide the parameters to be passed into `SQLBindParameter`?

Comment: Posted a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5636712/303363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to help determine the byte size of the parameter for certain types it's ignored for others.

Say you had a `SQLCHAR[10]` parameter you would pass `10` in as the column size:

```
SQLCHAR empStr[10];
SQLINTEGER len = SQL_NTS;
retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 10, 0, empStr, 0, &len);
```

Edit:

To be more clear variable types need to have sizes passed in especially variable sized types like strings so you know where the data ends in memory.  Types such as integers have statically defined sizes based on OS and environment so it's often optional to specify the size or there may be a constant defined that you can use instead of calculating.

Consider:

```
int smallInt = 5;
int bigInt = 234872634872;
char oneChar = 'A';
char charArray[128] = "CStyle String\0";

int smallIntSize = sizeof(smallInt);
int bigIntSize = sizeof(bigInt);
int oneCharSize = sizeof(oneChar);
int charArraySize = sizeof(charArray);
```

On my Windows 7 64bit machine using Visual Studio 2010 the size of both smallInt and bigInt are 4 the size of oneChar is 1 and the size of charArray is 128 even though the string it contains is much smaller it still has all that space allocated.

Comment: I am also curious to know why you pass 0 as the `BufferLength` (9th argument). Why do you not set it to 10 as well? To the best of my understanding, this argument is used only when a value is to be returned in the buffer during the execution of a SQL statement so that the returned value is truncated to this size in order to prevent a buffer overflow.

Am I correct?

Comment: The _BufferLength_ parameter allows you to truncate _ParameterValuePtr_ sizes on char and binary types it's ignored for every other type AFAIK.

Comment: A question on your edit. The length of the string parameter is already specified as a pointer to SQL_NTS as the `StrLen_or_IndPtr` argument (10th argument). Shouldn't that be enough to know precisely where the data ends?

Comment: Look at the definition of `SQL_NTS` it is actually the value of -3.  It specifies that you are using a _null terminated string_ the length can be calculated by the driver possibly but it's still preferable to explicitly pass in sizes if for no other reason than performance.

Comment: Oh and yes you are correct about the buffer overflow prevention usage of parameter 9 but since this example is a input param only not in/out nothing is coming back that we need to worry about overflows.

Comment: size of `smallInt` and `bigInt` are always the same

Answer (score 0):

`ColumnSize` argument corresponds to column size in your database scheme

*All character types*

*The defined or maximum column size in characters of the column or parameter (as contained in the SQL_DESC_LENGTH descriptor field). For example, the column size of a single-byte character column defined as CHAR(10) is 10.* ([ODBC Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/column-size?view=sql-server-ver15))

The `ColumnSize` argument of SQLBindParameter is ignored for fixed length (`SQL_INTEGER`, etc) data types. ([ODBC Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/column-size?view=sql-server-ver15))

When `SQL_PARAM_INPUT` it probably ignored by some drivers, but other may truncate your buffer to `ColumnSize`
*For variable-length data types, Size describes the maximum amount of data to transmit to the server. For example, for a Unicode string value, Size could be used to limit the amount of data sent to the server to the first one hundred characters.* ([.NET ODBC reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.size?view=netframework-4.8))

When `SQL_PARAM_*OUTPUT` some drivers failing to find column when `ColumnSize` is not specified (especially `[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error`) even when sending NULL.
*For bidirectional and output parameters, and return values, you must set the value of Size.* ([.NET ODBC reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.size?view=netframework-4.8))