# Can ColumnSize argument of ODBC SQLBindParameter be strlen(param) + 1 for SQLCHAR type parameter?

Tags: c++, c, odbc

The example for SQLBindParameter function at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963(v=vs.85).aspx passes the size of the character array as the ColumnSize argument (6th argument) when the C type is `SQL_C_CHAR`.

Quoting parts of the examples from that page:

```
SQLCHAR szEmployeeID[EMPLOYEE_ID_LEN];
SQL_DATE_STRUCT dsOrderDate;
SQLINTEGER cbCustID = 0, cbOrderDate = 0, cbEmployeeID = SQL_NTS;
```

...

```
retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT,
                           SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, EMPLOYEE_ID_LEN,
                           0, szEmployeeID, 0, &cbEmployeeID);
```

I want to know if it is okay to pass the length of the string parameter plus 1 as the ColumnSize argument. In other words, I want to know if the following call is okay if we assume that `szEmployeeID` contains a null-terminated string.

```
retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT,
                           SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, strlen(szEmployeeID) + 1,
                           0, szEmployeeID, 0, &cbEmployeeID);
```

I believe this can be very useful in calls like these:

```
SQLLEN nts = SQL_NTS;
retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT,
                           SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 6,
                           0, "hello", 0, &nts);

char *domain = "stackoverflow.com";
retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT,
                           SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, strlen(domain) + 1,
                           0, domain, 0, &nts);
```

Comment: I noticed that even if I pass 0 as the 6th argument (ColumnSize argument), I get correct results. I tried a query of the form `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column = ?` on Sybase SQL Anywhere. So, it seems like this argument is ignored.

Comment: Yes, this will work, I've used a similar approach when doing my own DB functions in C. It saves time and trouble.

Comment: Hmm, I've never tried passing it 0 before, you say this works? I just always gave it a computed value.

Comment: Albert, I pass a computed value too because I did not see any examples using 0 as the 6th argument on the web. However, 0 as the 6th argument works for me with Sybase SQL Anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is "Yes".